# Facebook pages tokens and uploads if not admin

Tags: facebook-graph-api, titanium, appcelerator

I have some questions about facebook pages and their access tokens.

Right now i am trying to build a mobile app for my band and i want to have a function in it that allows users to either take a picture or choose from the phone gallery and upload it to our fanpage on Facebook.

What i have understand when reading about this is that i can make an fb app and set the extended permission to `manage_pages` and then get the page access token from the page that i am admin for.

Well, every user of the mobile app wont be admin over our fanpage......

So i wonder if there is some way to get the fanpage access token and let user upload pics to our fanpage.

OR if you have any other way of doing it let me know.

I am building with appcelerator Titanium so i use javascript.

If you have an answer for this please explain like i am 6 years old.

Comment: You won’t need a page access token, if the page settings allow everyone to post photos to the pages wall – `publish_stream` will suffice in this case. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos

Comment: I have my page so that anyone can post whatever they want. But when i try to do this: `var data = {
     picture: image,
     message: 'My cool message',
      };
 
    Ti.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath(Titanium.App.Properties.getString("pageID") +'/photos', data , "POST", function(e){//some stuff };`       It wont put the image on the page but on my(!) wall  I can post messages to my page but not pics.